# Why is the b same as c at the console.log part? B should be same as c after the console.log

Tags: javascript

im trying to assign b to c after using c in the calculation, they cant be equal at the same time
right now the console.log returns them both with the same number

```js
let b = 1,
  c = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let a = b + c;
  c = a;

  a = b + c;

  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);

  b = c;
}
```

Comment: They aren't equal at the same time. `c` from the first iteration is equal to `b` from the second iteration, and so on.

Comment: Add `i` to the `console.log` lines so you'll see which iteration you're on.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the same, just add some separation to see in console.

```js
let b = 1,
  c = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let a = b + c;
  c = a;

  a = b + c;

  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  console.log('-------------------------');
  b = c;
}
```